# Invariant Violation: View config getter callback for component `article` must be a function (received `undefined`)

Tags: javascript, react-native, tradingview-api

I am getting this Error in React native. I decided to ask as Really I think I missed something at some point.

I am getting this as an Error trying to inetgrate Traderview in react native, What Did I miss? I get this as Error

```
Invariant Violation: View config getter callback for component `article` must be a function (received `undefined`). Make sure to start component names with a capital letter.
```

I do not see Article anywhere.

Here is my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text ,  } from 'react-native';
import TradingViewWidget, { Themes } from 'react-tradingview-widget';

export default class TraderViewShow extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
            <TradingViewWidget
            symbol="NASDAQ:AAPL"
            theme={Themes.LIGHT}
            locale="en"
            autosize
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

What did I miss here?